# Restore Postgre .BAT

Tags: postgresql, cmd, batch, bat

Estou fazendo um **.Bat** para **Backup** e um para **Restore** de um banco em **PostegreSQL**, o **.Bat** de Backup funciona perfeitamente, porem, o de Restore dá problema pelo banco possuir dados.

Teria alguma maneira de ao iniciar o **.Bat** de **Restore** excluindo todas as tabelas e só deixando o **BD** para não dar erro?

```bat
chdir C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin

ECHO "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin"
ECHO.
SET caminho=C:\
SET database=DATABASE
SET PGPASSWORD=1234

FOR /F "TOKENS=1-4 delims=/ " %%I IN ('DATE /t') DO SET data=%%I-%%J-%%K
FOR /F "TOKENS=1-2* delims=: " %%A IN ('TIME /t') DO SET hora=%%Ah%%Bm

ECHO ***********************************************
ECHO Aguarde, realizando o Restore do Banco de Dados
ECHO ***********************************************
ECHO.

pg_restore -U postgres -d %database% -1 %caminho%%database%_%data%.backup

PAUSE
```

Comment: Utilize a opção --clean no pg_dump que ele gerará os comandos adequados a limpar sua base antes de restaura-la.

Answer (score -1):

Não **seria o caso de aplicar um** <kbd>**[`drop`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073773/drop-postgresql-database-through-command-line)**</kbd> **antes?**

---

> - Update: ***obtenção de data no layout de forma mais rápida.***

Verifique as informaçõe da resposta desse <kbd>**[`link`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073773/drop-postgresql-database-through-command-line)**</kbd>

```cmd
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & cd /d "%~dp0" & set "_cmd=Get Day^,Month^,Year^,Hour^,Minute^"
cls & mode con cols=70 lines=8 & color 9F & title <nul & title Restore do  Banco PostegreSQL

rem :|  Cria variavel para data adicionando 0 para dia/mes/hora/minuto menores que 10... 
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims= " %%a in ('wmic Path Win32_LocalTime !_cmd! ^| findstr /r "[0-9]"') do (
     set "_y=%%e" & set "_m=0%%d" &  set "_d=0%%a" & set "_tt=0%%b" & set "_tm=0%%c" 
     set "_dt=!_y: =!_!_m:~-2!_!_d:~-2!" & set "_hora=!_tt:~-2!h!_tm:~-2!m"
    ) && set "_database=database" & set "_usuario=usuario" & set "_pgpassword=1234"

chdir /d "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin" && echo/"%cd%"

echo/ ***********************************************
echo/ aguarde, realizando o restore do banco de dados
echo/ ***********************************************

.\psql -U !_usuario! -c "drop database protodb"
.\psql -c psql pg_restore -u postgres -d !_database! -1 !_caminho!!database!_!_data!_!hora!.backup

timeout /t -1
```